# How to toggle two elements with the same button (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I have a button for a shopping cart item. If the toggle is on the background is green, if it's off the background is red. I want to toggle between the parent class at the same time as the button. So if the button is green, the entire list has a new class which I, later on, need to show all the items in the shopping list. I do not need to store any data, just give the idea of a webshop. It's like a checkbox, but I have to use buttons. (I used checkboxes for filters, but for this, a button is required). I am not allowed to use `JQuery`.

This is my HTML list which needs to change class with the button which is in the list:

```
<li data-type="speelgoed" data-wissel="" class="product" id="product1">
    <button class="material-icons" data-cart-toggle="1">&#xe8cc;</button>
    <figure><img src="/image/speelgoed/annaPop.png" alt="pop Anna"></figure>
    <h3><strong>Anna pop &#124; &euro;14.50 </strong></h3>
    <p>Leuke pop om mee te spelen. Haar en kleding kan aangepast worden.</p>
</li>
```

This is my javascript so far, this works for the button:

```
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
    const buyMe = evt.target;

    if(buyMe.dataset.cartToggle) {
        buyMe.classList.toggle("addedInCart");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the parent element in javascript by `parentNode` and for your case :

```
function handle(evt) {
    const buyMe = evt.target;

    const container = buyMe.parentNode; // li

    if(buyMe.dataset.cartToggle) {
        buyMe.classList.toggle("addedInCart");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added "container.classList.toggle("addedInCart");" and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `[element].closest` to retrieve the parent `li`-element. Example (dutch ;):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const buyMe = evt.target;

  if (buyMe.dataset.cartToggle) {
    buyMe.closest("li").classList.toggle("addedInCart");
    //    ^ find first parent li
  }
}
```

```css
li.product button:after {
  content: "In winkelwagen";
}

li.addedInCart button {
  color: green;
}

li.addedInCart button:after {
  content: "verwijder uit winkelwagen";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-type="speelgoed" data-wissel="" class="product" id="product1">
    <button class="material-icons" data-cart-toggle="1"></button>
    <!-- Note: img is random -->
    <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="pop Anna"></figure>
    <h3><strong>Anna pop &#124; &euro;14.50 </strong></h3>
    <p>Leuke pop om mee te spelen. Haar en kleding kan aangepast worden.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```